# The derivative of flow for an autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

We are considering an autonomous equation
$$\dot x=f(x),$$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ vectorfield. Let $\phi^t$ be the corresponding flow. Is it true that
$$D\phi^t(x)f(x)=f(\phi^t(x)),$$
why? $D$ stands for the Jacobian matrix of $\phi^t(x)$.

This is a question I encountered while I was reading researching articles:

Coomes, B. A., Koçak, H., Palmer, K. J. (1995). A shadowing theorem for ordinary differential equations. *Zeitschrift für angewandte Mathematik und Physik ZAMP*, 46(1), 85-106.

K. J. Palmer (1996) Shadowing and Silnikov Chaos. *Nonlinear Analysis, Theory, Methods & Applications*, 27(9), 1075-1093.

Palmer, K. J. (2008). Transversal periodic-to-periodic homoclinic orbits. *Handbook of Differential Equations: Ordinary Differential Equations*, 4, 365-439.

The authors simply state this is a fact on Page 96, 1077, 382 of the articles above, but without any derivation process. So I think this might come from some fundamental theory in dynamical systems. So I calculate like this:
$$D\phi^t(x(s))f(x(s))=D\phi^t(x(s))\dot x(s)=\frac{d}{ds}[\phi^t(x(s))]=f(\phi^t(x)).$$
I'm not sure if this is correct or in a standard way. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $D$ here? Spatial derivatives? Then, it could be either divergence $\nabla \cdot$ or gradient $\nabla$.

Comment: @DanDoe : There is a difference between derivative and gradient. The derivative is the Jacobian, the gradient is the transpose (or adjoint) of it, especially if it is a simple vector, that is, the derivative of a scalar function. And yes, in some domains the nabla symbol is also used for the derivative.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thank you for your advice. I have added context and my thought for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of the chain rule and the group property of the flow. Consider the $s$-derivative at $s=0$ of $$ϕ^{t+s}(x)=ϕ^t(ϕ^s(x)).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I've got it. If denote the flow $\phi^t(x)$ as $\phi(t, x)$, we have $\phi(t, \phi(s,x))=\phi(s, \phi(t,x))$. Then differentiate both sides with respect to $s$, $D\phi(t, \phi(s, x))\phi_s(s, x)=\phi_s(s, \phi(t,x))$. And this can also be written as $D\phi(t, \phi(s, x))f(x)=f(\phi(t, x))$. If set $s=0$, I can see the equality I want. But if we don't set $s=0$, does it mean $D\phi(t, \phi(s, x))f(x)=f(\phi(t, x))$ holds for any $s$?

Comment: Yes to the first part, No to the last, you have of course $ϕ_s(s,x)=f(ϕ(s,x))$, which only simplifies further for $s=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot!